# Pdf Preserve Layout to Text Haoop Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, pdf, mapreduce, recordreader

I need to convert a PDFPreserveLayout to text file in Mapreduce,I am using PDFBOX to convert a normal pdf file to text file,but it is not working for pdfpreservelayout.
Can any one help in solving this issue?